# Assign date/time parameter (%~t) extension within FOR loop

Tags: batch-file

First time poster... Apologies if I'm missing something simple...
When I try to assign the date/time within the `FOR` loop the same date/time is used for each file processed. I believe this is due to the *%* symbol being used rather than using the *!* symbol but I can't seem to find a way to get this to work. 
I have read

> "This variable substring syntax only works for CMD environment
>   variables, like %MYVAR%, it will not work with FOR parameter
>   variables, like %%G, however a simple workaround is to set a variable
>   first: Set %MYVAR%=%%G and then find the substring of the new
>   variable."

but it doesn't seem to work, I am assuming that that is because it is no longer a file, just a string and would have no date/time attributes??? 
Any suggestions would be very welcome.
Regards.

Command Line arguments (Parameters) (https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Variables: extract part of a variable (substring) (https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R %USERPROFILE%\Downloads %%F in (EPSG*.zip) do (
set name=%%F
set timestamp=%%~tF
set timestamp=!timestamp:~0,16!
set timestamp=!timestamp:/=!
set timestamp=!timestamp: =_!
set timestamp=!timestamp::=!
set destpath=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Nearmap\!timestamp!
powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Force -Path !name! -DestinationPath  !destpath!"
)
```

Comment: is there a reason you are mixing powershell and BAT/cmd stuff? what you are doing will work in one OR in the other ... if you stay in one & use the syntax that works in that shell.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I haven't really worked in powershell, but found that this command was producing the desired results in a way that my simple coding skills could figure out... Well, except the issue above..! Is there a way in batch that would work?

Comment: call a zip util that has a command line interface - like 7zip - and use that. otherwise, do this all in powershell. [*grin*] use `Get-ChildItem` to get the files, `Get-Date` to get the date & make the datestamp string, `New-Item` to make the destination dir, and then use `Expand-Archive` to expand the zips into the target dir.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks. I'll look into powershell some more. I am still a bit stumped though as the code seems close as I have it aside from the expansion of the _timestamp_ variable not being delayed to ensure a correct value for each iteration of the `FOR` loop. The powershell command itself works as expected.

Comment: i don't recall my old BAT/cmd stuff any more, so i'm useless on that. if your problem is the BAT stuff, then i recommend you remove the powershell tag since it makes folks think you are asking about PoSh, not cmd ... [*grin*]

Comment: `DestinationPath '%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Nearmap\%%~nF'"` line is odd. Are you sure that line is supposed to exist?

Comment: copy-pasted the batch part of your code to test - working fine here. If there is no matching file, the loop wouldn't even be executed (when you use a wildcard - without a wildcard, it's just a string, the loop will be executed, but as you suspected, there is no time when the file doesn't exist))..

Comment: Let me recommend two things: 1. quote the root path at `for /R`; 2. use the quoted `set` syntax `set "VAR=Value"`...

Comment: @michael_heath Thanks. Have removed this line. No it's not a part of the original code...

Comment: I'd go as far as to say, that in the code you have posted, other that the first line, `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`, and last line, `)`, every line is missing quotes, _(and all bar one of those should be indented too)_.

Comment: @michael_heath and others Thanks! I used your updated code and it works! Here's the embarrassing part... I realised that my code had probably been working all along. Because I am testing from home I had 3 _.zip_ files but had created all 3 versions from one master... (ie. same date/time..!) I apologise for wasting your time but truly appreciate your advice, it has been a great learning exercise and humbling for me. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

for /R "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" %%F in (EPSG*.zip) do (
    set "name=%%~F"

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "timestamp=%%~tF"
    set "timestamp=!timestamp:~0,16!"
    set "timestamp=!timestamp:/=!"
    set "timestamp=!timestamp: =_!"
    set "timestamp=!timestamp::=!"
    set "destpath=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Nearmap\!timestamp!"
    powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Force -Path '!name!' -DestinationPath '!destpath!'"
    endlocal
)
```

- Double quote the paths to avoid space and special character issues.
- Enable and disable delayed expansion in the loop can help avoid paths
  with `!` becoming invalid, if `!` exists and is stripped when enabled.
- The paths used in the powershell command can be single quoted
  (*which is treat as literal string which is fine for this*).
- The timestamp is locale based so cannot be sure if my test
  environment is similar to yours.